# Multicolumn table won’t complete

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The multicolumn table’s rows won’t join, picuture supplied.

[image]

This is what I’ve written for the table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Declension} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{First} & \multicolumn{2{|c|}{Second} \\ \hline
\textit {Strong} & \textit {Weak} & \textit {Strong} & \textit {Weak} \\ \hline
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Why won’t the lines join up and complete the table, what have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

(I’m a beginner)

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: take a look at this answer: [Table: problem in right most vertical line :(](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168960/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a missing `}`. You just have to add `&` in the empty line.

(Edit: considered comments of David Carlisle)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Declension} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{First} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Second} \\ \hline
        \textit {Strong} & \textit {Weak} & \textit {Strong} & \textit {Weak} \\ \hline
        & & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|c}{First} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Second} \\ \hline` should be `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{First} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Second} \\ \hline` although the error is more noticeable if you also add `\usepackage{array}`

Answer (score 2):

Replace, at the end of the table,

`\\ \hline
\\ \hline`

with

```
\\ \hline
&&&&\\ \hline
```

or

```
\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{}\\ \hline
```

depending on how many vertical  lines you want in the last row.